# How to make dropdown menu onclick and close when clicking outside element with Vanilla javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make dropdown menu onlick and close its menu when clicking outside element.

When i clicked on the News element it doesn't show anything.

I would like it to show when it's clicked and close it's menu when clicking anywhere.

```js
function dropDownMenu() {
    var btnNavNews = document.querySelector('.nav__news');
    var dropNewSub = document.querySelector('.nav__news__sub');

    btnNavNews.addEventListener('click', function () {
        dropNewSub.classList.toggle('show');
    })

    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target != btnNavNews && e.target.parentNode != dropNewSub) {
            dropNewSub.classList.remove('show');
        }

    })

}
dropDownMenu();
```

```css
/*Block*/
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}


/*Element*/
.nav__news__sub {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav__news__sub__ul {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background-color: grey;
}

.nav__news__sub__ul li {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.nav__content {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    margin-top: 50%;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}

.nav__item a {
    display: block;
}

.nav__item li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li <a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav__news" <a href="">News</a>

            <div class="nav__news__sub">

                <ul class="nav__news__sub__ul">
                    <li class="img" <a href="">Example</a>
                        <div class="nav__content">
                            <h1>Topic</h1>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li <a href="">Example2</a></li>
                    <li <a href="">Example3</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </li>
      
    </ul>




</body>
</html</html>
```

*Update my code is now works fine, i used wrong variable and change toggle method to remove method*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just used a wrong variable. You should use `btnNavNews` instead.

Although fixed, I think this logic is still wrong as it will toggle the dropdown if you click anywhere.

```js
function dropDownMenu() {
  var btnNavNews = document.querySelector('.nav__news');
  var dropNewSub = document.querySelector('.nav__news__sub');

  btnNavNews.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dropNewSub.classList.toggle('show');
  })

  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target != btnNavNews && e.target.parentNode != btnNavNews) {
      dropNewSub.classList.toggle('show');
    }

  })

}
dropDownMenu();
```

```css
/*Block*/

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Element*/

.nav__news__sub {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav__news__sub__ul {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav__news__sub__ul li {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.nav__content {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin-top: 50%;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.nav__item a {
  display: block;
}

.nav__item li {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li <a href="">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__news" <a href="">News</a>

    <div class="nav__news__sub">

      <ul class="nav__news__sub__ul">
        <li class="img" <a href="">Example</a>
          <div class="nav__content">
            <h1>Topic</h1>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li <a href="">Example2</a>
        </li>
        <li <a href="">Example3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </li>

</ul>
```

I suggest you use `remove` instead so that the dropdown will be hidden when you click anywhere else other than the "News" button:

```js
function dropDownMenu() {
  var btnNavNews = document.querySelector('.nav__news');
  var dropNewSub = document.querySelector('.nav__news__sub');

  btnNavNews.addEventListener('click', function() {
    dropNewSub.classList.toggle('show');
  })

  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target != btnNavNews && e.target.parentNode != btnNavNews) {
      dropNewSub.classList.remove('show');
    }

  })

}
dropDownMenu();
```

```css
/*Block*/

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Element*/

.nav__news__sub {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav__news__sub__ul {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav__news__sub__ul li {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.nav__content {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin-top: 50%;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.nav__item a {
  display: block;
}

.nav__item li {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li <a href="">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__news" <a href="">News</a>

    <div class="nav__news__sub">

      <ul class="nav__news__sub__ul">
        <li class="img" <a href="">Example</a>
          <div class="nav__content">
            <h1>Topic</h1>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li <a href="">Example2</a>
        </li>
        <li <a href="">Example3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </li>

</ul>
```